# OpenGL smoothing?

Tags: opengl, smoothing

[image: img191.imageshack.us/img191/4429/8mnk.jpg - image]

What is this white spot? It's appeared when i add to my code this:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND); //Прозрачность
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); 

glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_FASTEST); 
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);

glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST ); 
glEnable( GL_ALPHA_TEST );
```

How can i liquidate this? But i need smoothing...
Im using for columns

```
gluCylinder(quadric, column_width, 0, 1, 50, 50);
```

Comment: Save yourself a lot of trouble and don't use polygon smoothing. Just use full screen antialiasing, by requesting a multisampled pixelformat for your window and enable multisampling.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is because the polygons behinds are displayed. Try `glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST )` instead of `glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST )`.